# Status 404: ZF3 and Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, http-status-code-404, url-routing, zend-framework3

Nginx is giving me a 404 on my Laminas application when I try to navigate anywhere other than the base URL; from the looks of my log, it seems it is trying to serve routes as files/directories.

I used the information in the [Laminas MVC skeleton's README](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-mvc-skeleton#nginx-setup) to configure my VH; it looks to me like it *should* be passing the route to the public directory's `index.php`, but for some reason it is not.

Here is my configuration (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com`):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
 
    root /sites/domain.com;
 
    index index.php
 
    server_name domain.com;
 
    location / {
        index index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }
 
    location @php {
        # Pass the PHP requests to FastCGI server (php-fpm) on 127.0.0.1:9000
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /sites/domain.com/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    
        # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Having more than one `fastcgi_pass` seems wrong. Also, Laminas uses a `public` folder, does your `fastcgi_param` have that included, too?

Comment: @ChrisHaas `/sites/domain.com/` is a symbolic link to the project's public directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

- a location block to try all php, uris and html files (while keeping query string params)
- a single php block, passing to your fpm sock

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
 
    root /sites/domain.com;
 
    index index.php
 
    server_name domain.com;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
         

  location ~ \.php$ {
          fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
          fastcgi_index index.php;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          include       fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```